# XCode 7 Otool failing to copy file during build

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

[OSX 10.10.5, XCode 7.0.1]

I'm getting an error during my build stating that Otool can't copy a file:

```
error: otool: can't open file: /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.3.6.dylib: (No such file or directory)
```

The two lines before the error (and what I think is causing it, because there are no other error indications) are:

```
cp -p /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.3.6.dylib /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiCASE-asvgjysohljplretlamgcpgnxgiq/Build/Products/Debug/MiCASE.app/Contents/Frameworks
cp -p /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.3.6.dylib: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MiCASE-asvgjysohljplretlamgcpgnxgiq/Build/Products/Debug/MiCASE.app/Contents/Frameworks
```

When I manually perform the command in a terminal, it works fine.  I've set the permissions of the dynamic library to `me:admin 777`, so the file definitely exists.  Thus I don't understand why I am getting the error.

This leads me to believe there is something else that is failing but the build log isn't showing it.

I'm also getting this error at the end of the script, but I think it's due to the above:

```
Command /bin/sh emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

**Solution**
@trojanfoe, thanks for the info.

The problem was that as part of the build, a script was being run.  In the script `otool` was being used to extract dependencies, and filtering of its output was done incorrectly.  Fixing the filtering resolved the issue.

Comment: Remove the `:` after `.dylib`...

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what you use `libclang` for?

Comment: The line before it is the same but without the `:`, and it still fails during the build.  
Also, this is an auto-generated script, unless there is a way of editing it in the project's build settings.

Comment: @trojanfoe, we use it for cross-compiling and its our standard compiler.  It's installed via Homebrew.

Comment: And what do you do with it?  Why is `otool` generating the error when you say it's `cp` that is causing the issue?.  It's difficult to understand what you are doing and therefore impossible to know what's going wrong.

Comment: Well, as I explained in my question, I'm not sure it's the copy that is causing the problem because I can manually perform the command.  Perhaps Otool is failing somewhere else?  Or there is a `:` being inserted which shouldn't be there.  I'm looking at the build settings atm, but haven't found it yet.

Comment: You are almost certainly using `otool` to get values from the `dylib` that will be changed using `install_name_tool` so it works within the app bundle (i.e. `@loader_path...` or `@executable_path`).  There will be lots of scripting in there to fix-up issues like this.

Comment: thanks, I will have a look around and try to figure it out.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I think you are right.  `Otool` is extracting things from the dylib, and then `install_name_tool` is using the output.  Do you think it would be useful to post the script?

Comment: I know where the colon is coming from.  The output from running `otool -L /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.3.6.dylib` has `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libclang.3.6.dylib:` on the first line, and this is being included in the list of sub-libraries.  So the script needs to be corrected.